# Gtkmm Text Entry filters

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I am doing Gtkmm GUI programming now and I am new to this programming language. 
How to allow the user to only enter the numeric value in Gtkmm Entry text box.

Comment: you must handle the key events by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gtk::SpinButton instead of Gtk::Entry to allow numeric input only.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a key release signal for your Entry for example this is my entry "m_EntryAmount"

```
m_EntryAmount.signal_key_release_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Vente::entryKeyReleaseAmount));
```

and add the signal function

```
bool Sales::entryKeyReleaseAmount(GdkEventKey* /* event */ )
{
    if(m_EntryAmount.get_text()!="" && is_number(m_EntryAmount.get_text()) ){ 
       //now the Entry is not empty and its a number
       //do what you want here 

    }else{

      //here the Entry is not a number you can just delete it
      m_EntryAmount.set_text("");
}
    return true;
}
```

and add the is_number function

```
bool Vente::is_number(const string& s)
{
    return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(), 
        s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}
```

this is just a simple example to make an idea about that, you can do it by your self using your way

Comment: This should work, but I would expect the user experience to be rather ... nonpleasant. Imagine entering a long sequence of digits, perhaps by reading them off a piece of paper (not uncommon for financial data), then mis-typing a key (slipping to `p` instead of `0` or whatever) and having the application gleefully clear the entire entry. Not nice! The alternative is of course to filter *presses*, and just blocking non-accepted characters.

Comment: i know thats not a real solution but its just to help

Comment: to fix that you need to work on the entry key ( GdkEventKey ) not on the Entry itself. or stock the old value and back to it if any new char... there is a lot of ways to fix that.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your solution. I could circumvent it easily and have any text I want put into it. Text that goes into a Gtk::Entry can be entered not just by using the keyboard, but also pasting from the clipboard, assistive text entry, etc... The Gtk::EntryBuffer has the signal signal_inserted_text which you need to connect to if you need to filter text.